# After install ubuntu 12.10 no icons

Tags: icons

Im having a problem showing icons on the desktop screen after I installed ubuntu 12.1. I installed the software on a inspiron 5100 laptop. The unit has windows XP with service pack 3 also installed. The initial install after some difficulties eventually installed, allowing me to set some basic preferences from choices at the top of the screen, such as keyboard, networking etc. It also allows me to log on to the system, however once the desktop attempts to load a pink or orange screen desktop appears there are no options, no icons, just a pretty screen background. The mouse moves but neither right click or left click does anything, although a one time option to download updates was provided and I received them. I am 100 percent new to Linux and Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ive actually downloaded the image several times. with the same result. furthermore ive used image on 3 different machines. same result

Answer (score 0):

There might be two possible problems, first you might have used a corrupted disk/iso image.  Second you might have problem with your graphic drivers. In the first case try to redownload iso image.